# VBA SQL Server insert query

Tags: sql-server, vba, insert

I get an error:

[image]

when I execute this code:

```vb
Private Sub EditMethodAdd_Click()
MsgBox ("Add Click")

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim introw
Dim strState As String
Dim strsql1 As String
Dim strsql2 As String
Dim all As String

Dim strConn As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

MsgBox ("EditM1.Value:" & EditM1.value)


strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

strsql1 = " INSERT INTO dbo.Method(MethodID, MethodClass, Category, Description, Description2, MSA, ReqType, Equipment, Location, Spec1, Spec2, Spec3, Spec4, Spec5, Spec6, PilotingYN) "
strsql2 = "   VALUES( " & EditM1.value & ", Piloting, " & EditM3.value & ", Null, Null, Null, Null," & EditM2.value & ", " & EditM4.value & ", " & EditM5.value & ", " & EditM6.value & ", " & EditM7.value & ", " & EditM8.value & ", " & EditM9.value & ", " & EditM10.value & ", " & Null & " )"

all = strsql1 & strsql2
MsgBox ("ALL" & all)


Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open all, conn
MsgBox ("Insert Success")

EditMethodList.Requery

conn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

MsgBox "Data has been updated"
EditMethodList.Requery

End Sub
```

Is there anyone who can solve this problem?

I think I made the query fine, but this error keeps annoying me.

Any comments would be greatly thankful.

The MsgBox("All" & all) shows this results.
[image]

Comment: So what is the content of `all`? Clearly you didn't *made the query fine*, or you wouldn't be getting the error, but you decided not to show us the query you created that you showed yourself in the `MsgBox("ALL" & all)` line. It's not really helpful when you ask us to debug an issue with a query you're not going to show us because it's built using variables we can't see the content of, while you have code that shows it to you.

Comment: used parameter to prevent sql injection

Comment: Use `Debug.Print all` and edit your question to include the output.

Comment: what is annoying, is that you do not believe that you made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

As your MessageBox shows, you try to insert incorrect value `9.4.5V(LCO)+ICPqwer`.

What is the data type of `MethodID`?

- If it's varchar and contains `+ICPqwer` as part of the string, you
  should pass the whole string **quoted**, like this
  `'9.4.5V(LCO)+ICPqwer'`
- if it's a string but has a format `9.4.5V(LCO)`+ some other string
  (that is contained in ICPqwer), use `'9.4.5V(LCO)' + ICPqwer`
- if ICPqwer is a number, use this one: `'9.4.5V(LCO)' + cast(ICPqwer
  as varchar(100))`

Besides, all the other values seem also to be strings and should be quoted as well:

```
'Piloting', 'Internal Analysis', ...
```

The last thing: what are the "empty" values that you are passing in like `,,,`?
Pass the `NULL` explicitely, or if they are empty strings, pass them as `''`